# How can I customize partstack header in rcp application

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I am trying to customize PartStack header of a view in rcp application. My goal is to customize the coloring of the header and to add date and time to it and hide minimize and maximize buttons. Buttons can be hidden using css but other goals give me hard time. At the moment I am looking to use a custom renderer by overriding some methods in StackRenderer class. Is that a right approach or is there another renderer that I shoud use?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the min/max buttons then do not include `MinMaxAddon` in the Add On list in the Application.e4xmi.

Using a custom renderer for `StackRenderer` is useful for changing the text of the part tabs items. If you want to put text elsewhere on the part stack line you will probably need to look at the MinMaxAddon to see how it does that.

Comment: I was able to remove the min and max buttons wtih two lines of css: 
`.MPartStack {
  swt-minimize-visible: false;
  swt-maximize-visible: false;
}` 

The thing is that my application was made for Helios some years ago and it does not use e4xmi-files. Now have to port it to work on Luna. Writing text on partstack was achieved by some now deprecated libraries and are not functioning anymore.